# No constructor 'Text.' with matching arguments declared in class 'Text'

Tags: flutter, nosuchmethoderror, hot-reload

I'm using flutter module in my existing iOS app. While making changes I often use hot reload to see the output. It was working fine until yesterday, but when I use hot reload now, its giving me the exception:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building PurchaseOrders(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#4a83e]], state: _PurchaseOrdersState#a115b):
No constructor 'Text.' with matching arguments declared in class 'Text'.
Receiver: Text
Tried calling: new Text.()
Found: new Text.(String, {Key key, TextStyle style, StrutStyle strutStyle, TextAlign textAlign, TextDirection textDirection, Locale locale, bool softWrap, TextOverflow overflow, double textScaleFactor, int maxLines, String semanticsLabel, TextWidthBasis textWidthBasis, TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior}) => Text

Widget creation tracking is currently disabled. Enabling it enables improved error messages. It can be enabled by passing `--track-widget-creation` to `flutter run` or `flutter test`.
```

I've tried: File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart. But didn't help me out. I have to stop and run every time I make any small change. What could be the issue ?

Comment: The error says you are calling Text() constructor without parameter but you should be calling Text("text"). Are you sure you did not remove the parameter by mistake?

Comment: No. Its working fine with normal run, but the issue is with hot reload.

Comment: Are you running your app in `flutter beta`? Can you please provide your `flutter doctor -v` with latest stable, your `flutter attach --verbose` and [a complete reproducible minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It seems that [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61956) is related to your issue.

Answer (score 28):

I also faced a similar error, but it resolved when I `hot restart` the app instead of  `hot reload`.

Comment: flutter tip: always make hot-restart before after pass hours searching about solution ahah

Answer (score 0):

What Object are you trying to use on Text()? The error states `Text.()` is being tried to be used on `Text`: *"No constructor 'Text.' with matching arguments declared in class 'Text'."*. Text expects to have at least a String, and since no constructor matches `Text.()`, an error was thrown.

Are you using some kind of Localization for Text? In my experience, if you're using [flutter_localizations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), the app needs to be built at least once to generate the localized Strings. Otherwise, you'll need to provide [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to better understand the issue.